# Avoid colliding members in C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class

```cpp
template <typename T, typename W>
class A {
    void foo(W);
    void foo(T);
    void foo(int);
}
```

When `T=int`, `W=int`, or `W=T`, this class fails to compile. How can I get the methods to take priority over each other?

I want the priority `W > T > int`. So if `W=T`,  `foo(T)` is ignored and `foo(W)` is called. If `T=int`, `foo(int)` is ignored and `foo(T)` is called.

The compiler is VS2012, but I have Linux too, and will consider GCC/Clang solutions as well. Anything that compiles on any mainstream compiler goes, but only if you say what compilers it works on.

Comment: Looks like a job for `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think that if `enable_if` fails, class fails to compile.

Comment: I am almost hesitant to ask, but my curiosity often is my nemesis; *Why* ? What is this used for?

Comment: `std::enable_if<std::is_same<A, B>::value, A>::type` this type compiles and it's valid only if `A` and `B` are the same. You can adapt it to your needs. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if you should also specify the version of C++ that you are targeting.

Comment: `enable_if` , when used on a member function, can only operate on template parameters of that member function (not the template parameters of a class template containing that member function). So I don't see how it would work here.

Comment: @user2485710 all template functions must have a valid specialization or the program is ill formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @Yakk well, I'm also thinking about farwarding, but if OP doesn't specify the version of C++ that he is using, I'm afraid I can only offer a toy example with type traits.

Comment: @WhozCraig let's say both `W` and `T` are either `int`s or one of two `int`like classes of my own design. The custom classes have desirable features, while plain `int`s don't. OP edited to reflect compiler/C++ version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tag dispatch.  Override dispatching is easy to understand and scales.

We start with a perfect forwarder:

```
template<class U> void foo(U&&u){
  foo( std::forward<U>(u), std::is_convertible<U, W>{}, std::is_convertible<U,T>{} );
}
```

it creates tag types, in this case true or false types, to dispatch on.

This one:

```
void foo( W, std::true_type, ... );
```

catches everything that can convert to W.

Next, we block this one:

```
void foo( T, std::false_type, std::true_type );
```

from considerimg cases where the first argument can convert to `W`.

Finally, this one:

```
void foo( int, std::false_type, std::false_type );
```

can only be considered if the first parameter cannot convert to either.

Fancier tag types, or doing the dispatching one at a time, are both possible.

Sorry for typos.

I use a single C++11 feature -- `{}` to construct an object -- above.  If your compiler lacks support for that C++11 feature, simply upgrade your compiler, it is 2014, get with it.  Failing that, replace `{}` with `()`.

Comment: Wow! Nice! I had no idea about this pattern. Will try.

Comment: How much of a performance hit are we talking about? Can the compiler resolve this compile-time?

Comment: @pythonnut Yes.  The `true_type` are types, hence compile time.  Forwarding is nothing but a reference cast (a noop).  You could run into your optimizer failing because it gives up for no good reason, so if it is very important, profile, but there is nothimg findamentally being done, and this technique is used in `std` extensively.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are your dispatch parens not matched?

Comment: @pythonnut probably.  Design is sound, but my PC gave up ghost, so not tested.  ;)  Fixed a `)`<->`>` issue.  `is_convertible` may be spelled wrong, type args may be backwards, as well.  Ah, spurious `...` as well.  May compile now!

Comment: Am I wrong, or would that dispatch wrong for `A<long, short>`?

Comment: @deduplicator depends what wrong is: if `W` is supposed to dominate `T`, then no.  If exact match beats the dominance of `W` over `T` rule, then it would dispatch wrong.  You can handle that case however: the trick here is that this gives you complete control over dispatching.

Comment: Ok, so your solution overrides normal overload resolution completely. Good to know and (still) very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename W>
struct A {
    void foo(W) {}
    template<typename XT=T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<XT,T>::value
      && !std::is_same<T, W>::value, void>::type foo(T) {}
    template<typename XT=int> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<XT,int>::value
      && !std::is_same<int, T>::value
      && !std::is_same<int, W>::value, void>::type foo(int) {}
};
```

Added for testing:

```
template struct A<short,char>;
template struct A<char,char>;
template struct A<char,int>;
template struct A<int,char>;
template struct A<int, int>;

struct S {};

int main() {
    A<S, int>{}.foo(S{});
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (g++-4.9); apparently 0 can't be converted to the enable_if::type* thing. Is this a bug in gcc? (Anyway, it works with `nullptr` instead of `0`)

Comment: Also won't compile on Visual Studio because it doesn't support default template arguments on members.

Comment: @Brian: Changed and retested.

Answer (score 1):

For the relevant part of your template, you could use speclializations:

```
template <typename U, typename W>
struct Foo
{
    void f(U);
    void f(W);
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, T>
{
    void f(T);
};
```

For the rest of your class or class template, you can inherit from `Foo<A, B>` so you can keep the common code out of the part that needs to be specialized:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct TheClass : Foo<A, B>
{
    // common code
};
```

Comment: Would need **3** specializations, plus the base version!

Answer (score 0):

Try template specializations:

```
template <typename T, typename W>
class A {
    void foo(W);
    void foo(T);
    void foo(int);
};

template <typename T>
class A<T, T> {
    void foo(T);
    void foo(int);
};
template <>
class A<int, int> {
    void foo(int);
};
```

Comment: Would need **3** specializations, plus the base version!

Comment: Also you have to duplicate the remainder of the class contents for every specialization!

Comment: @Matt McNabb not if you inherit, which is what others suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without specializations of A, but with two helper structures in a few forms.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename W>
struct T_type { typedef T type; };
template<typename W>
struct T_type<W, W>  { typedef void* type; /*dummy type*/};

template<typename T, typename W>
struct int_type { typedef int type; };
template<typename W>
struct int_type<int, W> { typedef void** type; /*dummy type*/};
template<typename T>
struct int_type<T, int> { typedef void** type; /*dummy type*/};
template<>
struct int_type<int, int> { typedef void** type; /*dummy type*/};

template<typename T, typename W>
class A {
public:
    void foo(W w) {
        std::cout << "foo(W)" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo(typename T_type<T, W>::type t) {
        std::cout << "foo(T)" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo(typename int_type<T, W>::type i) {
        std::cout << "foo(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "A<float, char>" << std::endl;
    A<float, char> a;
    a.foo(1.0f);
    a.foo('1');
    a.foo(1);

    std::cout << "A<float, float>" << std::endl;
    A<float, float> b;
    b.foo(1.0f);
    b.foo(1);

    std::cout << "A<int, int>" << std::endl;
    A<int, int> c;
    c.foo(1);

    return 0;
}
```